# Linux Script: Command Line Argument

Tags: shell, command, arguments, line

Trying to write a script that accepts exactly one command line argument and must be a positive number. I have the one argument down, but can't figure out the positive number.
I have the following:

```
  #!/bin/ksh

  NUMBER=$1
  # Accepts only one argument or does not execute.
  if [ "$#" != 1 ]
  then
     echo "error: program must be executed with 1 argument."
     exit
  else
      if [ "$#" < 1 ] # **NEED HELP HERE**. Check for negative number.
  then
      echo "error: argument must be a positive number."
  fi
  fi
  do
         echo -n $NUMBER
         if [ $NUMBER -gt 1 ]
         then
            echo -n ", "
         fi
         NUMBER=$(($NUMBER - 1))
   done
   echo
```

...Need help with identifying if command line argument is a negative number.

Thanks

Comment: what do you consider a valid `positive number` ... only integers? floating/real (eg, 3.1415)? exponential notation (eg, 1e+5)? leading `+` (eg, +5)?

Comment: yes, only integers - 1, 2, 3, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Following will work:

```
test "$NUMBER" -ge 0 && printf "NOT NEGATIVE" || printf "NEGATIVE"
```

Comment: ksh: `NUMBER=1a ; test "$NUMBER" -ge 0 && printf "NOT NEGATIVE" || printf "NEGATIVE"` => `-ksh: test: 1a: arithmetic syntax error`, `NEGATIVE`

Comment: This didn't work for me. Even entering a positive number, I got "argument must be a positive number." I quite new at Linux scripts; I'm still learning. I don't understand the line.

Answer (score 0):

Verify it is a number using by checking the whether it is only digits:

```
#!/bin/ksh

NUMBER=$1
# Accepts only one argument or does not execute.
if [ "$#" != 1 ]
then
  echo "error: program must be executed with 1 argument."
  exit
else
  case $NUMBER in
    ''|*[!0-9]*)
      echo "error: argument must be a positive number."
      exit
      ;;
  esac
fi

while ! [ $NUMBER -lt 1 ]
do
     echo -n $NUMBER
     if [ $NUMBER -gt 1 ]
     then
        echo -n ", "
     fi
     NUMBER=$(($NUMBER - 1))
done
echo
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're only talking about positive (base-10) integers ... and excluding commas, exponential notation and leading plus sign (+) ...

```
# test for ${NUMBER} containing anything other than digits 0-9
if [[ "${NUMBER}" = @(*[!0-9]*) ]]
then
    echo "error: argument is not a positive number."
else
    echo "success: argument is a positive number"
fi
```

Obviously it becomes a bit more interesting as you strip away the assumptions on what's defined as a *valid* `positive number`.

---

Expanding on the solution proposed by [sqrt163](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2873201/sqrt163) ... a simple function should allow us to handle exponential notation, float/real and numbers with a leading plus sign (+), while allowing the calling process to filter out messages about syntax errors ...

```
$cat test.sh
#!/bin/ksh
NUMBER=$1
isnumber()
{
    # following should generate a non-zero for negative and non-numerics,
    # while allowing the parent process to filter out syntax errors

    [[ "${1}" -gt 0 ]]
}

# direct isnumber() output to /dev/null since we're only interested
# in the return code, and we want to mask any syntax issues if
# isnumber() is called with a non-numeric argument; unfortunately,
# for a valid numeric that contains a comma (eg, NUMBER = 1,000)
# our isnumber() call will fail

if isnumber ${NUMBER} >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo "${NUMBER} is a positive number"
else
    echo "${NUMBER} is not a positive number"
fi
```

And some tests ...

```
$ for s in 1 1.33 1e5 1e-4 +1 +1.65 +1e4 1,000 -1 -1.234 -1e5 -1,000 a b a1b ab1 1ab "a b c"
do
test.sh "$s"
done
1 is a positive number
1.33 is a positive number
1e5 is a positive number
1e-4 is a positive number
+1 is a positive number
+1.65 is a positive number
+1e4 is a positive number
1,000 is not a positive number
-1 is not a positive number
-1.234 is not a positive number
-1e5 is not a positive number
-1,000 is not a positive number
a is not a positive number
b is not a positive number
a1b is not a positive number
ab1 is not a positive number
1ab is not a positive number
a b c is not a positive number
```

This leaves us (I believe) with just the issue of an input containing 1 or more commas, which could be handled by stripping out the comma(s) using whatever method fits your fancy.